# Clear / Re-position marker (onClick)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How can I clear the recent markers or declare a new marker without using the .addMarker or new Tag? (or any way to do this, if you have an idea)

I use the codes below to add a marker(the one in comment) and it works but since it's in ".addMarker(new Marker...) tag, it creates a new marker every time I click my button. I tried to make a declared marker, and set the marker position, but I think it just doesn't work that way.

Concept: I'm getting my current location onClick, but it creates a new marker instead of re-positioning the last marker I have. T.I.A.

```
@Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

            mMap = googleMap;

            x = Double.valueOf(locX);
            y = Double.valueOf(locY);

            LatLng loc = new LatLng(x, y);

            //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).draggable(true).title("Building Location"));
            marker.setPosition(loc);
            marker.isDraggable();
            marker.setTitle("Building Location");
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc));
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
```

Comment: The only thing I managed to declare in my marker is:
Marker marker; 
I think I needed something more but I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can clear old marker before setting a new one like this -

```
mMap.clear();  //add this , it will clear old markers. if any
//then set new marker.
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(YOUR_NEW_LOCATION).draggable(true).title("Building Location"));
```